# set acl permission for tabs in Catalog Product Information

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, category-products

I need to remove all tabs except CATEGORIES and WEBSITES under Product Information.
[image]

How can I do that?

For  sales order view it was easy beacuse it was necessary only to override method canShowTab() but for catalog is not possible beacuse this methods does not exist. Any ideas?:-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In this case it is necessary to override function `beforeToHtml()` in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs` class and add there removeTab function.

```
 protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {

        $this->removeTab('id_of_tab_to_remove');
        ... parent code here ...
    }
```